# The reason why separation of variable works when solving laplace's equation in some cases

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, potential, coordinate-systems, differential-equations

Given an appropriate situation, for example, a case where there are 2 grounded conductors (infinite sheet charges), one at $y=0$ and one at $y=a$, and a 3rd conductor (at $x=0$) perpendicular to both, maintained at a potential $V_{0}(y) $, (This is the example situation given in DJ Griffiths 4th ed. Example 3, chapter 3) we can readily assume that the potential within the bounds takes the form $V(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)$ (there is an independence of $z$ axis in this case, but in a problem without $z$ symmetry its $V=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$) and we get a neat solution which turns out to be *the* solution, thanks to Dirichlet uniqueness theorem.

I'm not questioning the validity of the result, for I think it is airtight. (I suppose most would be satisfied with the use of uniqueness theorem and would move on) My question is, what exactly is the physical property of the situation, or perhaps mathematical property of the equation and the boundaries, that allows us to write this separable solution and get away with it? This obviously doesn't work in other cases, perhaps there are some symmetries that are being exploited? If so, what are they.

Comment: Separable solutions to linear partial differential equations often form a *basis* for the solution space. i.e. for Laplace's equation, any solution (not necessarily in the form $X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$)  may be written as a linear combination of separable solutions. In the Griffiths example, the unique solution just happens to be one of these basis solutions.

Comment: That separation of variables works is really a math problem, it's not physics deciding that his world. You might get a more satisfactory answer on mathematics stackexchange

Comment: My prof was openly claiming that this is magic, and we do not really know when it will work or when it will not, except in the case where symmetry dictates that it is obviously going to work. And that it is a seriously unhappy state of affairs since most non-trivial solutions are found by this method, so that we really need to know when it does not work, and what to do in that case. Note, however, that when linear combination of separable solutions is needed, that part is understood and not a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

That's a specific of the Laplace equation. The Laplacian is the square of the gradient with

$-\int dV f\left( x \right) \Delta g\left( x \right) = 
   \int dV \nabla f\left( x \right)  . \nabla g\left( x \right)$

In cylindrical coordinates the metric and the volume dV intoduce factor in between the product of tangential vector $\partial_i f $

$ \int \ dz \ dr \ r\ d\phi \left(\partial_r f, 1/r \partial_\phi f, \partial_z f\right)  . \left(\partial_r f, 1/ r \partial_\phi f, \partial_z f\right)$

Integration by parts yields our Laplacian in cylinder coordinates

$\Delta =  \partial_z^2 + 1/r^2 \ \partial_\phi^2 + 1/r\ \partial_r\ r \partial_r$

Since the right side is zero, we can try a product where each factor depends on its lower case variable

$f= Z\otimes \ \Phi \ \otimes R $

Then the partial derivatives and their prefactors, here only $r$, can be distributed over the tensor product, where each factor depends on the lower case variable

$ 0 == \partial_z^2 Z \otimes \Phi \otimes R + 
 Z \otimes \ \partial_\phi^2 \Phi \otimes 1/r^2 R 
  +  Z \otimes \   \Phi \otimes 1/r\ \partial_r\ r \partial_r R $

Now one is looking for eigenfunctions of the factors such that by division by the ordinary product such that some eigenfunctions disappear. Her it works for $Z, \Phi$

$ 0 == k^2  \otimes 1 \otimes R +  1 \otimes \ m^2 \otimes 1/r^2 R  
  + 1 \otimes \   1 \otimes R'' +1/r R'  $

$Z = e^{i k z },  \ \Phi = e^{i m \phi}   $

Now the sum over the last tensor factors has to vanish, that is the Bessel equation.

So, finally the question of separabilty  of the Laplace equation  in generalcan always  be reduced to making an ansatz with a common factor in a given geometry, that cancels the volume element and a product of functions of one variable, that eliminates all functions as eigenfunctions in the quotient, in simple cases.

The most complex cases break down to a system of ODE's of second order coupled in a linear system with the eigenvalues as free coefficients and factors from the metric coefficents.

All this goes under the name of Stäckel, Robinson and Eisenhart, who solved the problem of separability by  the so called Stäckel determinants for the Helmholtz and Schrödinger equations.

The inhomogenous equations $\Delta f + m^2 f ==0 $ in $R^3$ separates in the famous eleven system of coordinates, that represent threefold systems of orthogonal hyperplanes. This is by Eisenhart's work a property of the Ricci tensor in more general Riemannian geometries, allowing for a coupled system of quadratic constant momentum forms like p^2, L^2 etc.

The Lapacian has an infinity of such coordinate systems already in dimension two already:
$\delta f =0   \to \partial_z \partial_z^* f(z,z^*) ==0$

That is, any linear combination of holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions, depending on $z$ or $z^*$ only is a solution.

Any complex differentiable map generates a coordinate system with a separable metric.

All 2-d separable systems can be rotated around their symmetry axis yielding cylindrical systems of separabilty-